# 2 function asynchronous result 2.function for get,post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

2 function running my button action

```
favorite1 = (id,sender_id) => {

    if(this.state["like"+id]==true){
            this.setState({["like"+id]:false})
        }else{
            this.setState({["like"+id]:true})}


     //async or timeout how run 3-5 second for last result ----> this.favorite2(id,sender_id)
}
```

favorite1 function is button action for style but to much click very slowly button actions , i want to 3,or 5 second after run last result favorite2 function for favorite1 (id,sender_id), time out or asyn how can i do solution

```
favorite2 = (id,sender_id) => {

    // get or post process for favorite1 result
}
```

Comment: As I understood your question, you need: `setTimeout(()=> this.favorite2(id, sender_id, 3000)`. This will call your `favorite2` function after 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use standard de-bounce function:

```
function debounce(func, threshold, execAsap) {
  var timeout = null;
  return function() {
    var obj = this, args = arguments;
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    } else if (execAsap) {
      func.apply(obj, args);
    }
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
      if (!execAsap) {
        func.apply(obj, args);
      }
      timeout = null;
    }, threshold || 200);
  };
};

favorite2_deb3000 = debounce(favorite2, 3000); // 3000 miliseconds

favorite1 = (id,sender_id) => {
   favorite2_deb3000(id,sender_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async-await

```
async favorite1 = (id,sender_id) => {
         if(this.state["like"+id]==true){
            this.setState({["like"+id]:false})
        }else{
         this.setState({["like"+id]:true}
        }

     //async or timeout how run 3-5 second for last result ----> this.favorite2(id,sender_id)  
     // waits for 5 second
     let result = await favorite2(id,sender_id);

}

favorite2 = (id,sender_id) => {
    setTimeout(function(){

    // get or post process for favorite1 result
    }, 5000); 

}
```